# Liferay : Content Folder deleted from Admin but still in the data base

Tags: content-management-system, portlet, liferay-6.2

Now my customer complained that some images are not showing in his site in a web content portlet.
I investigated from the chrome console and found that the resource is not found (javascript error)
I took the uuid from the image url and checked if it's present in the DLFILEENTRY table and found it there
I also checked for the folder of the image in the DLFOLDER table and it was there also
I logged as ADMIN and navigated to the control panel then to 'documents and media' .... neither the image nor the folder where there !!!
I can't understand how this happens ... Isn't it supposed that whenever a folder is deleted it is no more in the database ???
I am not the site admin ... so I don't know what the admin did exactly
we are running liferay 6.2 on jboss

Comment: Did you check the trash bin inside site management?

Comment: actually I realized it was deleted physically due to a human mistake of the server admin